# PropertyConfigurator for Log4j does not exists anymore?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I only get this on the console:

> 13:08:18.379 [main] ERROR log4.prueba - This is Error
>
> 13:08:18.381 [main] FATAL log4.prueba - This is Fatal

I dont get a file or all the other levels.
What I am doing wrong?
My directory looks like this:

> projectFolder/src/log4/prueba.java
>
> projectFolder/src/log4j.properties

The code:

```
package log4;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class prueba {

     private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(prueba.class);
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
          logger.debug("This is Debug");
          logger.info("This is Info");
          logger.warn("This is Warn");
          logger.error("This is Error");
          logger.fatal("This is Fatal");
     }

 }
```

And the properties file look like this:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: how you are executing your java class ?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j 2 also supports configuration in properties files, but be aware:

- the file needs to be called `log4j2.properties`
- the [configuration syntax](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) is different from the Log4j 1.2 syntax (the configuration in the question uses the old Log4j 1.2 syntax, Log4j 2 will not understand this)

The Log4j 2 user manual has mostly XML examples, so many people find it easier to use the XML configuration syntax. (Again, the config file should be named `log4j2.xml`, Log4j 2 will ignore `log4j.xml`.)

Answer (score 1):

define log4j property file

@ `prueba.java`

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class prueba {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(prueba.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("This is Debug");
        ...
    }
}
```

@ `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

at `src/resources/log4j.properties`

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log/log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

output to `stdout` and `log/log4j-application.log` file

```
2018-05-11 14:29:43 DEBUG prueba:8 - This is Debug
2018-05-11 14:29:43 INFO  prueba:9 - This is Info
2018-05-11 14:29:43 WARN  prueba:10 - This is Warn
2018-05-11 14:29:43 ERROR prueba:11 - This is Error
2018-05-11 14:29:43 FATAL prueba:12 - This is Fatal
```